# D3D12 SDKLayers dll does not match the D3D12SDKVersion of D3D12 Core dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, crash, directx-12

So Recently I have been facing an error as I said in the title :

"D3D12 SDKLayers dll does not match the D3D12SDKVersion of D3D12 Core dll".

I Uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio and graphic tools but I get the same error.the error appears after loading this in:

" Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\wow64_microsoft-windows-directx-d3d12sdklayers_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.19041.1_none_a1efcfa6dbfde82c\d3d12SDKLayers.dll'."

d3d12core version : 10.0.19041.789

d3d12sdklayers version : 10.0.19041.1

Could you help me find the cause of this?

**UPDATE** : The crash happens during the swap chain creation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could refer to the link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/gettingstarted-dx12agility/#i-hit-d3d12_error_invalid_redist-887e0003-d3d12-sdklayers-dll-does-not-match-the-d3d12sdkversion-of-d3d12-core-dll

> A mismatch between D3D12SDKLayers (the debug layer) and the
> D3D12SDKVersion of D3D12Core.dll can happen if the System32
> D3D12Core.dll is loaded instead of the app local copy of
> D3D12Core.dll. This issue can be avoided by ensuring that all Agility
> SDK components are not in the same directory as the application exe,
> but a subdirectory instead.

Comment: @Amir Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us.
Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.